# How to stream a video on a webpage? H.264 format VLC player? or embed a video viewer

Tags: video, embed, h.264, vlc, viewer

I was wondering if there was a way to basically embed some sort of video viewer (ex. VLC or any player that supports H.264 format) into a web browser.  Basically, the live cam will feed data, and the viewer will be configured to get the data from a specific IP address and port number.

Any Advice appreciated,
D

Answer (score 2):

If you have a h264 stream, the easier is using the [FlowPlayer](http://flowplayer.org/) Flash player.

You can also embed VLC using this jquery plugin : http://revolunet.github.com/VLCcontrols (needs VLC activex or mozilla plugin installed)

Also note some IP webcams (like AXIS 206/207) provides MJPEG streams (yes, motion jpeg) or SWF streams which is very handy.

Answer (score 1):

**Paid:** solutions are Live RTMP Flash Streaming services.
**Free:** Try Justin.tv.
**Free** http://nchsoftware.com/broadcam (the only requirement is link back)

If you will stream from your own Computer/server the uplink speed  will be bottleneck.

Comment: What if you have your own type of web server, and you just want to stream from specified ip address and as no access to the internet only internal ip address...or an internal network...

Comment: You need some kind of streaming server. Although VLC supposed to do that i suggest you give broadcam a try http://www.nchsoftware.com/broadcam/ - its both server and embedded flv player for live and recorded videos.

Comment: VLC streaming seems to be easy but i couldnt run it under windows 7, just didnt streamed. And i don't how i would connect web vlc player into webpage.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use libvlc or libvlcnet (wrapper for .net) to convert the incoming streaming in a flash streaming. Then you can embed the flash streaming in any flash player in the web. Doing this you avoid the need of instaling extensions to the clients browsers.